# How to increase the window resize borders for VS Code, in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to play around with running VS Code, on my Linux system.

> Release Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa 64-bit
> Kernel Linux 5.4.0-73-generic x86_64
> MATE 1.2.4.0

And:

> Visual Studio Code
> Version: 1.56.2

And I'm finding it difficult to resize the window. It appears that the resize targets at the corners of the window are only a single pixel wide, and it is taking several attempts to grab them with the mouse.

I'm not seeing the same issue with other windows on my Linux desktop.

Is there a setting in VS Code preferences to increase the size of the window borders?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this isn't a VS Code setting, it's a MATE desktop setting.

From the Linux Mint start menu, bring up the "Appearance Preferences" control. On the "Theme" tab, select "Custom", then click on "Customize".

In the "Customize Theme" control, select "Window Border", then choose a different window border theme.

Some of them have resize hotspots that are narrow and difficult to grab, some of them are easy.